# Error loading UrlMappingsPlugin in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

When creating a basic grails plugin and compiling with Maven, I get this error message:

> Error loading plugin manager: Could not create a new instance of class
>   [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.mapping.UrlMappingsGrailsPlugin]!
>   (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Grails version 2.4.3

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue is to add the tomcat plugin (no idea why):

Add this to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
```

Then you may need to regenerate the pom.xml file using `grails create-pom`.

This appears to be related to [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817539/error-loading-plugin-manager-tomcatgrailsplugin-on-grails-2-3-database-migrat).