# Error loading plugin manager: Could not create a new instance of class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.mapping.UrlMappingsGrailsPlugin]

Tags: java, macos, maven, grails, groovy

Received the error message about loading UrlMappings Plugin in Grails when trying to create a grails plugin project and using the following commands:

`grails create-plugin user-management`

then in the user-management project:

`grails create-pom xxx.xxxxx`

`mvn grails:run-app`

I took a look at the suggested solution as described in [Error loading UrlMappingsPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975437/error-loading-urlmappingsplugin-in-grails/) and this solution did not solve my problem.

Details about System from maven info:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-15T04:37:52+10:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.1/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Please find below the full error message:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for xxx.xxxxx:user-management:grails-plugin:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 74, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building user-management 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.4.4:run-app (default-cli) @ user-management ---
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
.....................Error
|
Error loading plugin manager: Could not create a new instance of class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.mapping.UrlMappingsGrailsPlugin]! (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been fixed in Apache Maven 3.2.3 as everything now works fine without any errors.

Comment: I tried to update to mvn version 3.2.3 and even 3.3.9 but still the same error.